# create ArrrayList from Type in java

Tags: java, class, reflection, arraylist

Why this is not possible ?

```
Type type = newResponse.getDataType().getType();
Class<?> tClass = type.getClass();                
Type arrayType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<tClass>>(){}.getType();
```

Complete deserializer is as follows -

```
public class NewJsonDesrializer implements JsonDeserializer<NewResponse> {

    @Override
    public NewResponse deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {

        JsonObject jsonElement = json.getAsJsonObject();
        NewResponse newResponse = new Gson().fromJson(json, typeOfT);
        JsonElement data = jsonElement.get("data");

        if(data.isJsonArray()){
            Type type = newResponse.getDataType().getType();
            Class<?> tClass = type.getClass();

            Type arrayType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<tClass>>(){}.getType();

            newResponse.setData(new Gson().fromJson(data, arrayType));


        }else{
            newResponse.setData(new Gson().fromJson(data, newResponse.getDataType().getType()));
        }


        return newResponse;
    }
}
```

This throws error in deserializer above at line -

```
Error:(36, 54) error: cannot find symbol class tClass
```

Complete NewResponse class is as follows-

```
public class NewResponse<T> implements Serializable {
    private boolean status;
    private String message;
    private T data;
    private Constants.DataType dataType;

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Constants.DataType getDataType() {
        return dataType;
    }

    public void setDataType(Constants.DataType dataType) {
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }
}
```

Enum that returns `Type` is as follows -

```
 public enum DataType{
        @SerializedName("user")
        USER(User.class);

        Type type;

        DataType(Type type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public Type getType(){
            return type;
        }
    }
```

Json structure is as follows -

```
{  
   status:true,
   message:"Registration Complete.",
   dataType:"user",
   data:[  
      {  
         username:"sachin@example.com",
         email:"sachin@example.com",
         created_on:"1426663448",
         last_login:null,
         active:"1",
         first_name:"Sachin Gutte",
         last_name:"",
         company:null,
         phone:null,
         sign_up_mode:"GOOGLE_PLUS"
      },
      {  
         username:"administrator",
         email:"admin@admin.com",
         created_on:"1268889823",
         last_login:"1425373557",
         active:"1",
         first_name:"Admin",
         last_name:"istrator",
         company:"ADMIN",
         phone:"0",
         sign_up_mode:"SOMEAPP"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: You can only specify types in type parameters directly, not indirectly through a variable. 

But, since type parameters in Java are not preserved at runtime (at runtime, a List has no idea whether it's a list of Integer or something else), why would you need specify it through a variable?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Im using Gson to parse the data. Code is part of deserializer. Jsone sometimes return single object or list of various class types ie models I hav e. Will update question with details.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Please see the updated question. Json in question is also posted.

Comment: How does the update make a difference? `Type arrayType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<tClass>>(){}.getType();` is a strange line. `TypeToken` doesn't know what type of ArrayList it is parametrized with - this information isn't kept at runtime. And why are you creating an anonymous subtype of TypeToken and then calling the `getType()` method? How would this be any different from not creating an anonymous subtype?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment.

You have to know the type by compile time, not runtime. Thats why it cannot be resolved. Have a look at this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html